# Issues properly formatting Android TrafficStats Value

Tags: java

I'm attempting to format a trafficstats value so it displays as 12.22 MB (instead of 12.00000 as it displays now) however I'm continually getting force close errors when using the following method:

```
String.format("%1$,.2f", info);
info += ("\tWifi Data Usage: " + (double) (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000  + " MB");
info += ("\tMobile Data Usage: " + (double) (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000  + " MB");
```

P.S.

I've also attempted to use the following method (after 1st answer below)

```
NumberFormat nf= new NumberFormat();
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        String result= nf.format(info);
```

However it results in: "Cannot instantiate the type NumberFormat" although import java.text.NumberFormat; is being called

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting. The entire stack trace would be best

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `String.format()` prior to your concatenations?

Comment: No - I just want to shorten the end value (by any means necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became a hot mess really quickly. Squishing your code and Henry's code together should work and look something like this...

```
double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
totalBytes /= 1000000;
mobileBytes /= 1000000;

NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
String info = String.format("\tWifi Data Usage: %s MB\tMobile Data Usage, %s", totalStr, mobileStr);
```

And info should contain the string you're looking for.

Comment: Shaded - you are my hero. 

P.S.

A hot mess is an understatement - thank you VERY much!!

Comment: @AmaniSwann No worries, if you're going to keep coding in Java I suggest you take some time to understand the code and brush up on some basics. Other than that, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

### Using NumberFormat

`NumberFormat` is [abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), which means you cannot possibly instantiate it as-is. You need to either use the `NumberFormat.getInstance` method, which will create an anonymous concrete subclass for you, or instantiate a concrete instance yourself. You probably want the second way, which would look something like this:

```
// DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat.
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // Set the format to "#.##"

String result = nf.format(11.987654321); // result is now the String "11.99"
```

You can change the format by changing what formatting string you pass to the `DecimalFormat` constructor. The example here will give you two decimal places, but the whole specification is also available [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

I'd also clean up your beginning parts to make them clearer and easier to read. Here's a simple rewrite with every step laid out explicitly:

```
String info = "";
double mobileMB = (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() / 1000000.0);
double totalMB = ((TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()) / 1000000.0) - mobileMB;

NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String totalMBString = nf.format(totalMB);
String mobileMBString = nf.format(mobileMB);

info += String.format("\tWifi Data Usage: %sMB\tMobile Data Usage: %s", 
        totalMBString, mobileMBString);
```

---

### Using String.format

You do also have another option. Since this is a pretty simple application, the number-formatting options of `String.format` might be easier for you to use than the full power of `NumberFormat`. In that case, you would want to do something like this:

```
info += String.format("\tWifi Data Usage: %.2fMB", /* Put a number in here */);
info += String.format("\tMobile Data Usage: %.2fMB" /* Put the other number in here */);
```

This way will always result in two decimal places, though, so you'll get `12.00MB` instead of `12MB`.

Comment: I implemented the method suggested - the end value has not changed. (It is still showing as 12.13243)

Comment: @AmaniSwann The example I gave will produce values rounded to two decimal places. You can change the format by changing what string you initialize it with; [see the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of?:

NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
info = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(nf);

Comment: @AmaniSwann What? That doesn't make any sense. My example does what you want. Use `NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");` and `result = nf.format(info);`

Comment: I apologize. (Thank you for your help btw!) When using the method: 

NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

  String result = nf.format(11.987654321);
  
  result = nf.format(info);


I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: @AmaniSwann Sorry, I didn't notice that `info` is a string. You can't use a `NumberFormat` to format a string, you need to give it a number. So what you want is to use `nf` to parse your numbers, *then* add the parsed numbers to the `info` string. You should also probably break up that first part so you can see what you're doing, instead of putting it all in one huge line.

Comment: No prob - Can I apply it directly to the Traffic Stats value?

Comment: @AmaniSwann You have to declare `result` somewhere, because Java is explicitly-typed. The first time you use `result`, it should be `String result = null;` (or whatever other value you want). As to the Traffic Stats value, you can apply it to any number you want. But make sure it's a real number, and not a String (or a `byte[]` which is what it kind of looks like you're getting).

Comment: Understood. I tried applying it to the line: info += ("\tWifi Data Usage: " + (double)  (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000  + " MB");

by using the method:

info += ("\tWifi Data Usage: " + (double) result) = nf.format((TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000  + " MB");


but I'm getting "the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable." and I'm not sure how to rewrite it

Comment: @AmaniSwann That's why I said you should break up the first part. You're trying to do too much in one line, and it makes it difficult to read and therefore difficult to fix. Make your numeric values a variable, and then format them into strings, and then put those values into `info`.